# Remove quotes from the string value of a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to count the lines of each text file in a directory on the condition that a text file with the same filename also exists in a second directory or one of its subdirectories. The script should count the lines of both files. Here's my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R "C:\Users\ABC\Documents\" %%W IN (*.txt) DO (
    FOR /R "C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\" %%J IN ("%%~nxW") DO ( 
        IF EXIST "%%J" (
            set "firstfile=findstr /R /N "^^" "%%W" | find /C ":""
            FOR /F %%G in ('!firstfile!') do set firstfilelines=%%G
            set "secondfile=findstr /R /N "^^" "%%J" | find /C ":""
            FOR /F %%H in ('!secondfile!') do set secondfilelines=%%H
            ECHO %%W has !firstfilelines! lines.
            ECHO %%J has !secondfilelines! lines.   
        )   
    )               
)

pause
```

It counts the lines of text files in the first directory C:\Users\ABC\Documents\ but not in C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\ because findstr cannot recognize the value of %%J as a file path because it puts quotes around the filename as in C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\folder\"file.txt". How do I get rid of these quotes?

Comment: The second `for` won't work without `*` in the search pattern.

Comment: But it does. Try it. My only problem is the stubborn quotes.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, it lists all the found paths and blindly appends the file name even if it doesn't exist there. Well, thanks to `if exist` check it's not a problem.

Comment: `IF EXIST "%%~J"` and `"%%~W"` and similar.  Just add a tilde where you want the surrounding quotation marks stripped.

Comment: @rojo I already tried it. It did not strip the quotes but it stripped the last backslash in the file path as in C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\folder"file.txt"

Comment: BTW why complicating with the temporary `set`? `FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%G in ('find /c /v "" "%%W"') do set firstfilelines=%%G`

Comment: @wOxxOm I can write it that way but it still won't solve the %%J variable problem

Comment: The `%%J` problem might be solved by using `"%%~fJ"`; to get the number of lines in a file you could use this line: `for /F "delims=" %%G in ('find /C /V "" "%%~fW"') do (set "FirstFileLines=%%G" & set "FirstFileLines=!FirstFileLines:*: =!")` (no `findstr` is required);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `dir /s /b` to build a list of files in the second folder
- Use `find /c /v "" filename` to count the lines faster
- Use `set /a` to trim the spaces in the assignment of the number

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "folder1=C:\Users\ABC\Documents\"
set "folder2=C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\"

FOR /R "%folder1%" %%W IN (*.txt) DO (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%J in ('dir /s /b "%folder2%\%%~nxW"') DO (
        IF EXIST "%%J" (
            FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%G in ('find /c /v "" "%%W"') do set /a L1=%%G
            FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%G in ('find /c /v "" "%%J"') do set /a L2=%%G
            ECHO %%W has !L1! lines.
            ECHO %%J has !L2! lines.
        )
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: Thanks! You are a lifesaver!